# How to track campaigns other than Apple search Ads in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I wan to run campaigns other than Apple search Ads, how can I check from which source the app has been installed in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

You measure performance of campaigns by creating special campaign links for each campaign. Campaign links can be created in App Store Connect.

(App Store Connect-> App Analytics -> Sources -> Campaigns -> Generate Campaign Link)

Source: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/itcfa7936330?sub=apdff205b72c0994

Comment: thanks for the reply, but by using that link I will be able to see the count of each campaign in AppStore 

but I want to send the call to my server when the app first open that from which campaign the app was installed